# Elasticsearch Java Client Jackson Mapper pollutes Spring Jackson Mapper

Tags: elasticsearch, jackson, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I'm updating my Spring Boot project to version 3.0.0 of Spring Boot.
One important dependecy is the Spring Data Elastic Repository. I included the starter dependency:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch")
```

After updating the dependecies, my unit test are failing, because no more null values are provided by the web controller. I tried to change the behavior by using the property inclusion configuration:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    default-property-inclusion: always
```

This did not help. I debugged the code party and it seems like the new Elastic Java Client has it's own Jackson Mapper config, which sets the global config to 'NON_NULL'.

```
package co.elastic.clients.json.jackson;

...

public class JacksonJsonpMapper extends JsonpMapperBase {

    private final JacksonJsonProvider provider;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

   ...

    public JacksonJsonpMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this(
            objectMapper
                .configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, false)
                .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL),
            // Creating the json factory from the mapper ensures it will be returned by JsonParser.getCodec()
            new JacksonJsonProvider(objectMapper.getFactory())
        );
    }

...
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a soultion for the problem. Spring Boot has an autoconfiguration for the Elastic Jackson mapper. This autocofiguration uses the same ObjectMapper as the web controller:

´´´

```
package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.elasticsearch;

...

/**
 * Configurations for import into {@link ElasticsearchClientAutoConfiguration}.
 *
 * @author Andy Wilkinson
 */
class ElasticsearchClientConfigurations {

@ConditionalOnMissingBean(JsonpMapper.class)
@ConditionalOnBean(ObjectMapper.class)
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
static class JacksonJsonpMapperConfiguration {

    @Bean
    JacksonJsonpMapper jacksonJsonpMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new JacksonJsonpMapper(objectMapper);
    }

}
```

...

´´´

It is possible to override this Bean to copy the ObjectMapper instance and create an own ObjectMapper for the Elastic client:

´´´

```
@Configuration
internal class CustomJacksonJsonpMapperConfiguration {
@Bean
fun jacksonJsonpMapper(objectMapper: ObjectMapper): JacksonJsonpMapper {

    return JacksonJsonpMapper(objectMapper.copy())
}
}
```

´´´